# How to remove TypeScript error (in VSCode) that can run in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I'm trying out the [performance measurement code](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#performanceentryduration) from Nodejs in VSCode.
The code works when I run it in Nodejs, and there were no errors reported.

However, in VSCode, there's error wriggles and tsc --build doesn't compile the code.
I have tsconfig.json created by tsc --init, as well as installed @types/node with npm.
I've also closed and reopened the folder after installing @types/node.

How do I remove the error wriggles, so that tsc can compile/build it?

I will be re-using this code in a project that I need tsc to compile/build.

[image: Error wriggles in VSCode]

These are the errors.
[image: Errors]

Comment: on the error wriggles, what errors arre you seeing?

Comment: Thanks, @ApoorvaChikara! Updated post with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Remove "dom" from "lib" in tsconfig.json

[image]